# How to make a dynamic breadcrumb CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

How to make a dynamic breadtsrumb CakePHP ?
For example, I have a url
http://site.com/post/first/add
To breadcrumb automatically generated in such Layouts
Home > post > first > add

Answer (score 2):

Using the HTML Helper:

```
echo $this->Html->getCrumbs(' > ','Home');
```

Other examples:

```
$this->Html->addCrumb('Users', '/users');
$this->Html->addCrumb('Add User', '/users/add');
```

More info: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1653/Creating-breadcrumb-trails-with-HtmlHelper

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

try this link.it will solve you issue
http://www.codetweet.com/php-2/breadcrumb-helper-class-in-cakephp/